# Get Object by condition in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, react-component

i have a file jsx like

```
const Routes = {
    item: '/Dev/Item',
    count: '/Dev/Count',
};

module.exports = Routes;
```

i want the object in condition wise like

```
const Routes = {};
    if(true){
        this.Routes = {
            item: '/Dev/Item',
            count: '/Dev/Count',
        };
    }
    else{
      this.Routes = {
            item: '/Prod/Item',
            count: '/Prod/Count',
        };
    }

    module.exports = Routes;
```

i can import this file at any component and can access Route.item or Route.Count
how can i do this with if Else?

Comment: your const scoped in condition body. Move `module.exports` to condition body, or use ternary operator `module.exports = true ? {} : {};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const` is block scoped, so `Routes` will not be defined after your if statement.

You could instead create a variable with `let` before the if statement and assign a value to that.

```
let Routes;

if (true) {
  Routes = {
    item: "/Dev/Item",
    count: "/Dev/Count"
  };
} else {
  Routes = {
    item: "/Prod/Item",
    count: "/Prod/Count"
  };
}

module.exports = Routes;
```